# Using peewee and now need integrate with mssql (SQL Server)

Tags: python, sql-server, peewee

I've an application developed with peewee to use mariadb, but now, I need duplicate the 'insert' to register it in a mssql (Microsft SQL Server) database.
I'm trying to use [peewee-mssql](https://github.com/cour4g3/peewee-mssql) and [peewee-mssqlserv](https://github.com/brake/peewee_mssql) database drivers (or frameworks, or libraries, i'm confused about how they are called) but it seems that the select and insert functions differ from those defined in original peewee and I don't find documentation or API about this peewee-mssql drivers.

How can I use the same classes to insert records in mariadb and mssql indistinctly? It's possible?

Thanks once again.

Comment: Depends on what Peewee version you're using. I took a quick look at those libraries and it seems that they are not compatible with Peewee 3.x, which overhauled the SQL generation code.

Comment: Damn it! I'm using 3.1.3 peewee version. BTW, thanks for the great peewee library. Do you recommend something similar to peewee for mssql?

Comment: For Peewee 2.x, the issue is that peewee-mssql requires an additional parameter `params` which is optional in the parent class - Peewee's `Database`. So you can pass in an empty tuple. I guess it's similar for inserting.